# How to animate linear gradient of the background clip

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am trying to animate the `linear-gradient` of a `background-clip` from 0% to {0-100}%.

This is my CSS but unfortunately it is not animating between the percentages just changing to the percentage after 5 seconds:

```
.train{
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar 5s;
    -moz-animation: progress-bar 5s;
    animation: progress-bar 5s;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-color: #bc2122;
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
  from {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #67A062 0%, #67A062 0%, #bc2122 0%, #bc2122 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #67A062 0%,#67A062 0%,#bc2122 0%,#bc2122 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #67A062 0%,#67A062 0%,#bc2122 0%,#bc2122 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=#67A062, endColorstr=#bc2122,GradientType=0 );
  }
  to {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #67A062 0%, #67A062 60%, #bc2122 60%, #bc2122 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #67A062 0%,#67A062 60%,#bc2122 60%,#bc2122 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #67A062 0%,#67A062 60%,#bc2122 60%,#bc2122 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#67A062, endColorstr=#bc2122,GradientType=0 );
  }
};
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tkfj136/5/)

Comment: `background-image` is not animatable.

Comment: Sorry where am I using `background-image`?

Comment: Inspect your element in Chrome, hit the dropdown for `background: ..` and see where your `linear-gradient` is being applied.

Comment: How do you "hit the dropdown for background"?

Comment: Ah, well, it is being applied as an animation so it won't show up on the element itself. `linear-gradient` gets applied/assigned to `background-image` when used as shorthand within `background`.

Comment: oh :( is there anyway around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163286/discussion-between-wild-beard-and-maximilian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot animate `background-image`. Instead, you can animate `background-size` to make the gradient fill 100% of the height smoothly:

```css
.train {
  font-size:35px;
  font-weight:900;
  animation: progress-bar 5s infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-color: #bc2122;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #67A062 0%, #67A062 60%, #bc2122 60%, #bc2122 100%);
  background-size: 100% 0%;
  background-position:bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
  from {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 100% 0%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}

;
```

```html
<div class="train">
Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to use SVG instead. You can animate the text fill gradient, animation is smooth as silk, and it will have **much better browser support** than the `background-clip:text` you're using to style that icon.

```css
/* Main styles */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);

.text {
  fill: url(#gr-radial);
}

/* Other styles */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #222;
  font: 14.5em/1 Open Sans, Impact;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 300">

  <!-- Gradient -->
  <radialGradient id="gr-radial"
                  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70%"
                  >
    <!-- Animation for colors of stop-color -->
    <stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="0">
      <animate attributeName="stop-color" 
               values="#bc2122;#67A062;#bc2122;"
               dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
    <stop stop-color="rgba(55,55,55,0)" offset="100%"/>
  </radialGradient>

  <!-- Text -->
  <text text-anchor="middle"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
        dy=".35em"
        class="text"
        >
    Text
  </text>
</svg>
```

My understanding of SVG is pretty limited at the moment (working on it ;) ), so that's a blatant copy-paste, but I think it serves to show the idea and with a little time on reading the specs you'll be able to use it for your icons ;)